# Using SharePoint 2013 Geolocation Field as a Search "Distance" Refiner

Tags: 2013, search, refiner, geolocation

Does anyone know of any working examples of using the new Geolocation field as a SharePoint 2013 search refiner? We would like to tag items with their location and then enable end-users to filter content search results based on a chosen distance from a designated postal (e.g. zip) code. i.e. I want to see all items within 5 miles of my post code.

Has anyone done this yet?

Comment: We would also need to sort by distance. There is mention of distance sorting in the following link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj938031.aspx. There's no mention of using the Geolocation field type specifically, we could just use a longtitude and latitude fields I suppose.

Comment: So having done a bit of proof-of-concept work it seems the geolocation field does not get indexed by search so I have had to create Longtitude and Latitude fields. I'm still no closer to getting these working as refiners though as the data needed to build the refiners (the distance from a user-chosen point) is not in the index either, and can only be calculated at run-time for each user query.

Comment: http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/bas/archive/2012/07/25/indexing-the-new-geolocation-field-in-sharepoint-2013-technical-preview-is-not-possible-yet.aspx